# JSON schema requiring patternProperties

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator, python-jsonschema

I'm looking for help in defining the JSON schema which would validate the below sample JSON. I don't know the country codes before hand, so they can be any country code actually. In other words, I cannot use "US" or "IN" directly in the schema. Each country code must have exactly 5 values in the list

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "country_metric": {
        "US": [1,2,3,4,5],
        "IN": [9,0,1,4,5],
        "AU": [7,7,7,7,7]
    }
}
```

I realize I must use **patternProperties**, but cannot figure out exactly. Any help is very appreciated.

I was trying something like this, but it does not seem to work-

```
{
    "definitions": {},
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#", 
    "$id": "https://example.com/object1659608644.json", 
    "title": "Root", 
    "type": "object",
    "required": ["id", "country_metric"],
    "properties": {
        "id": {"type": "integer"},
        "country_metric": {
            "type": "object",
            "patternProperties": {
                "^[0-9]+$": {"type": ["array"], "items": {"type": "integer", "minItems": 5, "maxItems": 5}}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The key of a `patternProperties` object is a Regular Expression. You must define the Regular Expression you want there to allow for two capital letters.

Alternativly, you could use [propertyNames](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/object.html#property-names) with an enum of all the allowed values.

Comment: @Relequestual- Thanks for your comment. I think the country code is fine and does not need to be validated by the schema. I'm looking at how to validate that there are exactly 5 elements in the list

Comment: If you don't care about that, you can use `additionalProperties` which will apply to all properties.

Comment: What @Relequestual is saying is that the regular expression in `patternProperties` applies to the _property name_.  "US" is not a match for `^[0-9]+$`.  You need to change that to `^[A-Z]{2}$` to match a country code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `minProperities` and `maxProperties` to constrain how many properties are in your objects.

```
  "$minProperties": 5,
  "$maxProperties": 5
```